# Thin plate piezoelectric transducer glued to flat surface in shear mode

Tags: oscillator, crystal, piezo, piezoelectricity

I want to glue a piezo plate looking like in the image below such that the wide surface of the plate gets glued onto a flat surface. The image is part of the datasheet from [here](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/43406.pdf).

If I apply an AC voltage to the piezo plate such that it starts expanding and contracting along the flat surface it's sitting on, will the plate fall off?

I have no actual experience with piezo and wanted to see if gluing a thin piezo plate on a flat surface and have it expand parallel to the surface it's sitting on is feasible. 
The 2nd image below is what I want to achieve and I was wondering if it really does happen without changing the height  (if it really does only move laterally)

(the 2nd image is from [here](https://www.physikinstrumente.com/en/technology/piezo-technology/properties-piezo-actuators/displacement-modes/))

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's more of a mechanical engineering question then an electrical engineering question, isn't it?

Comment: @MarcusMüller My apologies, I just edited my question. It may still be a mechanical engineering question but I guess now I'm asking how a piezoelectric shear actuator does move sideways without changing its height

Comment: a) these dimensions aren't to scale; nothing says it doesn't change its height in here (probably just insignificantly). b) Piezo crystals move by changing their crystal structure periodically; when changing a crystal structure, conservation of volume isn't a given fact.

Comment: @MarcusMüller it wasn't, for which I apologize.

Comment: no need to apologize!

Answer (score 1):

You probably need something like a [flexible epoxy adhesive](https://www.intertronics.co.uk/product/irs2125-high-performance-flexible-epoxy-adhesive/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes the adhesive should be very low modulus and bond strongly. High modulus and strong bonding would also prevent falling off, but will also clamp the actuation. I have used single component PUR glue in the past which is rubber soft after curing. I suppose this could work well.